How many different bridge hands contain 4 of 1 suit, and the of each of the other suits?
In bridge the total number of cards must add up to 13. The question asks how many 4-3-3-3 combinations are possible.
The answer states the following:
$\binom{4}{1}$$\binom{13}{4}$$\binom{13}{3}^3$
Why is my answer incorrect (below)? Shouldn't one account for the fact that there are fewer suits to choose from for each subsequent 3 cards?
$\binom{4}{1}$$\binom{13}{4}$$\binom{3}{1}$$\binom{13}{3}$$\binom{2}{1}$$\binom{13}{3}$$\binom{1}{1}$$\binom{13}{3}$

No.
First, I will examine why the offered solution is correct.  Then, I will examine your approach.
First of all, there are $~4~$ ways of choosing which suit will have $~4~$ cards.  So, reserve the factor of $~4,~$ and then assume, without loss of generality, that there are $~4~$ spades, and $~3~$ each of the other $~3~$ suits.
Note that it doesn't matter what order the cards are drawn in.  At this point, all that matters, once the factor of $~4~$ is reserved, is determining how many distinct ways there are of being dealt $~4~$ spades, $~3~$ hearts, $~3~$ diamonds, and $~3~$ clubs.
This explains why the offered solution is correct.

Explaining why your solution is wrong is somewhat challenging, because you didn't really explain where the additional factors of $~\displaystyle \binom{3}{1}, ~\binom{2}{1}, ~\text{and} ~\binom{1}{1},~$ came from, other than to say that

Shouldn't one account for the fact that there are fewer suits to choose from for each subsequent 3 cards?

So, I will try to reverse-engineer your thinking, and then explain why it is wrong.  I am assuming (perhaps wrongly), that your thinking is as follows:
There are $~4~$ ways of choosing which suit gets $~4~$ cards, and then $~\displaystyle \binom{13}{4}~$ ways of choosing the $~4~$ cards of that suit.
Now, there are $~3~$ suits left to deal with.  There are then $~\displaystyle \binom{3}{1}~$ ways of choosing which suit then gets $~3~$ cards, and then $~\displaystyle \binom{13}{3}~$ ways of choosing the $~3~$ cards of that suit.
Now, there are $~2~$ suits left to deal with.  There are then $~\displaystyle \binom{2}{1}~$ ways of choosing which suit then gets $~3~$ cards, and then $~\displaystyle \binom{13}{3}~$ ways of choosing the $~3~$ cards of that suit.
Now, there is $~1~$ suit left to deal with.  There are then $~\displaystyle \binom{1}{1}~$ ways of choosing this suit, and then $~\displaystyle \binom{13}{3}~$ ways of choosing the $~3~$ cards of that suit.
To illustrate why this is wrong, consider the following scenario:
The bridge hand consists of

A,2,3,4 of spades
A,2,3 of hearts
A,2,3 of diamonds
A,2,3 of clubs

So, to begin with, the distribution of the spades is correctly dealt with by the pair of factors $~\displaystyle \binom{4}{1} \times \binom{13}{4}.~$
However, now watch what happens when trying to find the right factors to enumerate the rest of the cards.  Suppose that you incorrectly distinguish (for example) each of the following distributions as distinct.

Cards 5,6,7 are hearts, Cards 8,9,10 are diamonds, Cards 11,12,13 are clubs. 
Further, as suggested above, none of the hearts, diamonds, or clubs are above a $~3.~$

Cards 5,6,7 are hearts, Cards 8,9,10 are clubs, Cards 11,12,13 are diamonds. 
Further, as suggested above, none of the hearts, diamonds, or clubs are above a $~3.~$

Cards 5,6,7 are diamonds, Cards 8,9,10 are hearts, Cards 11,12,13 are clubs. 
Further, as suggested above in each hand, none of the hearts, diamonds, or clubs are above a $~3.~$

Cards 5,6,7 are diamonds, Cards 8,9,10 are clubs, Cards 11,12,13 are hearts. 
Further, as suggested above, none of the hearts, diamonds, or clubs are above a $~3.~$

Cards 5,6,7 are clubs, Cards 8,9,10 are hearts, Cards 11,12,13 are diamonds. 
Further, as suggested above, none of the hearts, diamonds, or clubs are above a $~3.~$

Cards 5,6,7 are clubs, Cards 8,9,10 are diamonds, Cards 11,12,13 are hearts. 
Further, as suggested above, none of the hearts, diamonds, or clubs are above a $~3.~$


Your enumeration would be perfect, if the $~6~$ bullet pointed distributions above were to be considered distinct.  The reason that your enumeration is wrong is because these distributions should not be considered distinct.  That is, the order (i.e. cards 1-4, cards 5-7, cards  8-10, cards 11-13) that the suits appear as the 13 cards are being dealt is totally irrelevant.
When determining whether one distribution of $~13~$ cards is distinct from  another distribution of $~13~$ cards, the only question is:  is there some card in the first distribution that is not present in the second distribution?
Assuming that this is not the case, the fact that (for example) in the first distribution, the first card was the Aces of Spades, while in the second distribution, the thirteenth card was the Ace of Spades is totally irrelevant.

User2661923 perfectly explained why you are wrong. Just one more detail : your method would be correct if the question was for example : how many 5.4.3.1 combinations are possible. And I let you find : how many 4.4.3.2 combinations are possible.
